# Writing on dxf file - swift

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to find a way to create and write on dxf file.
So, I found a project on the net written on Objective C.

I am still a newbie and hope to get some help.
When I run the application, it gave the following error:

*Assigning to 'id _Nullable' from incompatible type 'SnapSystemLayer *__strong'*

the error appear in the following code:

```
    CALayer *snapLayer = [CALayer layer];
    snapLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
    snapLayer.delegate = snapSystemLayer;
    [self.layer addSublayer:snapLayer];
    [snapLayer setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: Isn’t that Objective C code?

Comment: yes, objective C code

Comment: Why does the title say "Swift"? Which line exactly is causing the error? It's probably the `snapLayer.delegate = snapSystemLayer;` line. You need to assign to the `delegate`, something that conforms to the `CALayerDelegate` protocol. And it appears that `snapSystemLayer` is of type `SnapSystemLayer` which does not conform to the CALayerDelegate protocol.

Comment: Can you please help? how to sort this issue out?

Comment: No one have an answer?